# Upper and Lower bounds for the function

Tags: recurrence-relations

Please find the upper and lower bounds of the recurrence relations.

$T(n)= 4T(n−2) + 6T(n-3) + 3^n $ if $n>=3$

$T(n)= 1 $ if $ n <=2$

I am confused. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Have you computed the first few values to get any insight into how the values behave?

Comment: How tight do you need the bounds to be? One easy one is that $ 0 \leq T(n) \leq 1000000^n$.

Comment: I am new to this topic bro. What is the tightest bound possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Have a look to the first terms : you have $T(0)=1$, $T(1)=1$, $T(2)=1$, $T(3)=37$ ... The next term is composed by the addition of previous positive terms plus $3^n$. So, a lower bound is clearly $3^n$ and an upper bound is infinity.

To give you an idea $$T(10)=141,787$$  $$T(20)=10,086,292,531$$ $$T(30)=613,731,130,507,819$$  $$T(40)=36,431,449,755,746,056,291$$

**Added after Gerry Myerson's comment**

I do not know how to prove the following. What I did was to plot $log(T(n))$ as a function of $n$ and the result is almost a straight line from which it seems that $3^{n+1}$ is an upper bound ($3^{10}=59,049,3^{11}=177,147$), ($3^{20}=3,486,784,401,3^{21}=10,460,353,203$),($3^{30}=205,891,132,094,649,3^{31}=617,673,396,283,947$), ($3^{40}=12,157,665,459,056,928,801,3^{41}=36,472,996,377,170,786,403$)

May be, considering the series defined by $U(n)=T(n)/3^n$ could help ... but the CAS I use just gave up.

Comment: But perhaps OP wants a tighter upper bound, dependent on $n$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson. You are right ! Let me think about this. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help guys. A tighter upper and lower bounds would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence is (starting at n=0) 1, 1, 19, 37 ,163, 505,.. It has the generating function
$$\sum_{n\ge 0}T(n)x^n=\frac{1-2x+12x^2-18x^3}{(3x-1)(6x^3+4x^2-1)}$$ and follwing Binet's formula we can decompose this into partial fractions
$$\ldots \frac{1}{1/3-x}-\frac{0.862..}{0.39602..-x} - \frac{0.4313..-0.716..i}{x+0.5131..+0.372..i}+cc$$.
If each of these 4 terms is re-expanded in its geometric series, the bounds for large $x$ should emerge.